# Can compile and run in ifort but not gfortran (Mac M1)

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, julia

I'm trying to create a a shared library object from Fortran objects and load it in Julia. When using ifort, with the below command, it runs no problem:

```
ifort x.f90 y.f90 z.f90 -o Library.so -shared -fpic -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
```

When I run the following command using gfortran:

```
gfortran x.f90 y.f90 z.f90 -o Library.so -shared -fpic -ffree-line-length-300 -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
```

Julia doesn't appear to be able to find the library:

```
could not load library "/Users/X/Documents/Library.so"
dlopen(/Users/X/Documents/Library.so.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/X/Documents/Library.so.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/Library.so.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/Library.so.dylib' (no such file)
```

Comment: Looks like some assumption at `Julia`'s side. `macOS` typically has `.dylib` ext. for shared libraries. You can enforce it to something else. Take a look how `ifort` really generates the lib. Is it `.dylib` or `.so`. Also, try symlink `Library.so` with `Library.so.dylib`

Comment: @Oo.oO, when manually changing from the extension of the ```Library.so``` to ```Library.dylib``` it fixed the issue. Julia looks at the platform and enforces the extension!